# How to import a py file function in monkeyrunner test file

Tags: android, python, import, module, monkeyrunner

I want to create test cases for my Android application in Monkeyrunner.

I am thinking to create a sub tests case file to do before actual test case. like a install , uninstall functions in a separate py file. How can i call these install/uninstall apk or any other function in my monkeyrunner test case?

I have a successful experiment of calling a function from other imported py file in my py file in PYTHON. but same function cannot called while running through monkeyrunner.

```
import new
print new.foo()
```

this is working while running through python but not working in monkeyrunner.
Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

monkeyrunner (jython) and python should import modules exactly the same way, the only difference might be the content of the module search path.
To verify it try:

```
   import sys
   print sys.path
```

in both python and monkeyrunner and see if there are any differences.
If you want to include some path, do

```
   sys.path.append("/path/to/my/new/module")
   import new
   print new.foo()
```

and should work.

Comment: Getting the following error by following your insturctions.     new.foo()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'foo'

Comment: So there is no foo in new. Post more info